# Какие потоки можно назвать фоновыми?

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность

Потоки с меньшим приоритетом можно назвать фоновыми относительно потока с большим приоритетом?

Answer (score 2):

В программировании обычно фоновым потоком называется поток, который делает задания «незаметно для пользователя», в фоне. При этом приоритет потока не так уж и важен.

С практической точки зрения, работа делится на *видимую пользователем* (обновление UI) и *невидимую*. Стандартом для UI-программирования является один UI-поток, при этом остальные потоки считаются фоновыми.

---

В .NET, для сравнения, понятие фонового потока «материализовано» в стандартной библиотеке. Там основные, не фоновые потоки — это потоки, которые держат приложение в живых. Если все не фоновые потоки завершаются, приложение завершается, обрывая при этом и фоновые потоки.

Answer (score 0):

> Какие потоки можно назвать фоновыми?

Ответ зависит от используемой ОС.

В люнихе всё просто - там более корректно использовать термин "процесс". Поток - частный случай процесса, разделяющий общие данные с другими потоками (нитями). Поэтому словосочетание "фоновый поток" звучит очень странно.

Если же говорить о процессах, то там критерий абсолютно однозначный, что бы процесс стал фоновым, он должен выполнить два действия(как минимум):

1. закрыть stdin, stdout и stderr;
2. отсоединится от управляющего терминала.

Про виндовоз говорит не буду, так как там понятия поток, нить и процесс как-то очень сильно затуманены...